# Get XVisualInfo for Vulkan

Tags: opengl, vulkan, xlib, glx

For OpenGL with Xlib, in order to create a window, we can get the appropriate `XVisualInfo` from GLX and pass it to `XCreateWindow`. However, if I want to use Vulkan with Xlib, how do I get the proper `XVisualInfo`? Do I still have to link with GLX?

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan does things differently in that regard. First and foremost, because of the experiences with OpenGL and the way it interacts with windowing system a very different approach was chosen.

With OpenGL traditionally you create a rendering context from the properties of a certain drawable. In Microsoft this is tighter coupled to windows, since the selection of the visual format happens based on the pixelformat of the drawable (aka Window) which device context you use for render context creation. In GLX there's no tight tie in with drawables, but you still have to create a context matching for to the visual and framebuffer configuration of the drawables you want to draw to.

*Vulkan doesn't work that way!*

First in forremost in Vulkan there no longer are contexts. What you got are *instances*. And for each instance you create handles to *physical* and logical *devices*, for which in turn you create *images* to draw upon. All of this happens completely separated from the windowing system. As a matter of fact, its trivial to do headless rendering with Vulkan.

If it took extra effort to do headless rendering with OpenGL, with Vulkan it is the other way round: It takes extra effort to render to a window.

The key to that are so called "swap chains". Swap chains are what current day drivers and GPU architectures use to manage the delivery of images to the display (the buffer *swap* of double buffering and the "SwapBuffers" call you'd do with OpenGL is in that name). To create a swap chain you first obtain a Vulkan surface for the drawable you want at the receiving end of the swap chain. The functions for that are part of window system dependent extensions to Vulkan; they are extensions so that they don't clutter the Vulkan core with Window System Integration (WSI) related thing. For X11 you'd either use [`vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR.html) or [`vkCreateXlibSurfaceKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCreateXlibSurfaceKHR.html).

With the surface created you iterate over its queues to see what operations it supports using [`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR.html), and then what image formats it can be used with using [`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR.html). ***This very step is the closest match to querying the `Visual`s and `FBConfig`s in relation to creating a GLX context, to answer your question.***

Once you've decided upon a format you create a swap chain, for which you must again so dome housekeeping, namely check what capabilities the surface brings (capabilities here means, methods by which it can transfer data along the chain). The functions for that are [`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.html) and  [`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR.html).

With all the information you've obtained until this point you now decide on the format and configuration of the swap chain and create it using [`vkCreateSwapchainKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCreateSwapchainKHR.html). That being done you obtain the images of the swap chain using [`vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR`](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR.html).

Now that you have the images of the swap chain, you can create views on them as usual and use them as attachments to render to. Congratuations on shaving that Vulkanic yak **Phew**.

Comment: Thanks. One question though: it seems that I need `Display` and `Window` handles before calling `vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR` (stored inside `VkXlibSurfaceCreateInfoKHR`). Only then can I call `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR`, etc. However, I need `XVisualInfo` to create `Window`. So, do I use a create a dummy window to query correct parameters, or can I just pass `XMatchVisualInfo`'s output in `XCreateWindow` and be done with it?

Comment: @marked-off-topic: You just create the window as usual. Neither `Visual` nor `FBConfig` are tied to OpenGL/GLX at all. It's just by happenstance (and lazyness of the developers back then), that GLX uses the window visual as a side channel for context setup. `Visual` are part of X11 core, and `FBConfig` come with the XRender extension. – The nice thing with Vulkan is, that neither instances nor devices are tied to it whatsoever (in contrast to OpenGL); only swap chains depend on it, and that's it.

Comment: No, what I am asking is how to make sure that the `Visual` passed to `XCreateWindow` is "compatible" with Vulkan, when the functions (`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormat`) to get that information seem to rely on a window already existing? (and do I even need to worry about compatibility?)

Comment: @marked-off-topic: I see. Well, the thing is, you can always enumerate the image formats that are supported by a device. With that information you can determine the intersection of the sets of image formats supported by Vulkan, and the image formats supported by your X connection, and choose the visual from that. However most of the time the set of direct color X11 Visuals and FBConfigs will be a true subset of the image formats supported by the vulkan instance for the corresponding device.

Comment: @marked-off-topic: And if everything else fails, you can always go the last effort route and **not** create a swap chain, and instead do "headless" rendering with a roundtrip via a XShm pixmap: It's slightly (or worse) efficient, but it will always work.